# Why can't I call on the operator when I return by value instead of by reference?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, return-value

This code would work IF I was returning by reference.  My question is why can't I return by value ?

```
/* Boss is a struct I defined, but is literally empty */

ostream operator<<( ostream & speak, Boss y ) {

  speak << "We need more profit!" << endl;
  return speak;

}

int main() {

  Boss b;
  cout << b << endl;

}
```

My speculation was that maybe it is because you can't call on functions with temporary objects, but I've called on functions with temporary objects before. Is this something specific to operators ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `ostream` is a non-copyable object. Returning "by value" means returning *a copy*. Standard `ostream` class does not have an accessible copy constructor, which is why it is impossible to copy `ostream` objects.

This is done intentionally, specifically in order to prevent your from copying `ostream` objects. There are at least two reasons why it is so.

Firstly, `ostream` is essentially an abstract class, intended to serve as a base class implementing common functionality for more specific classes like `ofstream` or `ostringstream`. Objects of `ostream` class by themselves are incomplete and unusable. Copying such objects does not make any sense - it will simply slice the object.

Secondly, when an object has exclusive ownership of some external resource, like an input-output stream, copying such object would imply duplicating that external resource as well. In many cases it is physically impossible (e.g. a program can only have one standard output stream). But even when it is possible, it is still not a good idea to make as easy as a simple copy constructor call.

In modern C++ (C++11) objects like that often support *move semantics*, which makes it possible to pass such objects around "by moved value" (let's call it that). But since `ostream` is just a base class, in `ostream` the corresponding constructor is protected, i.e. it is not accessible from outside. It becomes publicly accessible only in more specific stream classes, like `ofstream` or `ostringstream`.

Comment: My god I learn something new everyday with this language. 
By any chance, do you know the reasoning behind making an object non-copyable ?